# How to pass variables to metafieldsSet mutation in Shopify Api Node js Grahql client?

Tags: node.js, graphql, shopify

I was trying to use the `metafieldsSet` mutation to update metafields in `Shopify` with the following code:

```
const client = new Shopify.Clients.Graphql(
        process.env.SHOP,
        process.env.PASSWORD
    )
    try {
        const metafields = await client.query({
            data: `mutation metafieldsSet($metafields: [MetafieldsSetInput!]!) {
                metafieldsSet(metafields: $metafields) {
                    userErrors {
                        field
                        message
                    }
                    metafields {
                        key
                        value
                    }
                }
            }           
            `,
            query: {
                metafields: [
                    {
                        key: 'cb_inventory',
                        namespace: 'my_fields',
                        ownerId: 'gid://shopify/ProductVariant/40576138313890',
                        type: 'number_integer',
                        value: '25',
                    },
                ],
            },
        })
        console.log(metafields)
        res.status(200).json({ values: metafields })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.status(500).json(error)
    }
```

However, the above mutation returns the following error:

```
Expected value to not be null
Variable $metafields of type [MetafieldsSetInput!]! was provided invalid value
```

I assume the variable `metafields` failed to pass into the mutation because when I run the exact same mutation in the `Shopify Admin API GraphiQL explorer`, there was no error
[Shopify Admin API GraphiQL explorer mutation result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M9TU.png)

I have also looked into the [github repo](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-node-api/blob/main/docs/usage/graphql.md) of @shopify/shopify-api.  In my understanding, variables are added to the `query` object.

What am I missing?

Thanks,

Howard

Environment: Next js 11.1.2,

Dependencies: `@shopify/shopify-api` 1.4.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out the syntax is incorrect.  The variables should be placed inside the `variables` object, while the mutation statement should be placed inside the `query` object.

The following code works now:

```
const metafields = await client.query({
   data: {
      query: `mutation metafieldsSet($metafields: [MetafieldsSetInput!]!) {
         metafieldsSet(metafields: $metafields) {
            userErrors {
               field
               message
            }
            metafields {
                key
                value
            }
         }
    }`,
       variables: {
           metafields: [
              {
                 key: 'cb_inventory',
                 namespace: 'my_fields',
                 ownerId: 'gid://shopify/ProductVariant/40576138313890',
                  type: 'number_integer',
                value: '25',
             },
           ],
       },
   },
})
```

ref: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-node-api/blob/main/src/clients/graphql/test/graphql_client.test.ts

To use the intended API version, you need to first initialise the context with the following code:

```
Shopify.Context.initialize({
    API_KEY,
    API_SECRET_KEY,
    SCOPES: ['read_products', 'write_products'],
    HOST_NAME: HOST,
    API_VERSION: '2021-10',
})
```

Comment: You are legend. Thanks.